# How to use TB_GETITEMRECT in c#

Tags: winapi

I am trying to get the window handle of a button inside a toolbar.  I came across a blog which said that TB_GETITEMRECT can be used using SendMessage to get the window handle of a button inside a toolbar.

But, I could not find any example for the same?

Comment: Please don't edit the question to ask a different question. If you have another question, please ask a different question. You are allowed to ask more than one question.

Comment: Don't read blog entries that suggest, that [TB_GETITEM**RECT**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787340.aspx) could be used to retrieve a window **handle**.

Answer (score 1):

Toolbar buttons are not windowed controls. So you cannot obtain a window handle for a toolbar button.

Comment: Is it possible to get the bounding rectangle of the buttons inside a toolbar?

Comment: You asked how to get the window handle. That's what the question says.

Comment: OK, I will ask it as a different question.